# Stop workflow when an item is changed

Tags: workflow, email

I am trying to stop the workflow when “Status” is changed to something other than “Pending”.

Do I create another step?

[image]

Is it supposed to look like this:

[image]

or:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, it looks like you just need to add an Else branch to your If statement (assuming this workflow would run on item change). Something that looks like this:

[image]

Cheers,

-Drew